# How can I add any URL in this button HTML code?

Tags: html, json, url, button, href

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-3">Order now</button>
```

I have already tried adding href in between but it's not working.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-3" href="http://webofpicasso.net">Order now</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap your button In an anchor tag.

like this:

```
<a href="http://webofpicasso.net" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-3">Order now</button></a>
```